# Write string 16-bit fasm assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, osdev, fasm, video-memory

I made driver that should to work with vmem, but it doesn't work. I think mistake is registers that I uses to direct to the memory.

there is code of driver:

```
;;;;;;; Primary Video Driver
PVideo:
                .treadbyte:    ; in:eax=ID, [0 - 3440]; out:cl=BYTE [0 - 255]
                        push eax ebx
                        mov ebx, 0xb8000
                        imul eax, 2
                        inc eax
                        add ebx, eax
                        mov cl, byte[ebx]
                        pop eax ebx di
                        ret
                .treadattr:    ; in:eax=ID, [0 - 3440]; out:cl=BYTE [0 - 255]
                        push eax ebx
                        mov ebx, 0xb8000
                        imul eax, 2
                        add ebx, eax
                        mov cl, byte[ebx]
                        pop eax ebx
                        ret
                .twritebyte:   ; in:eax=ID, [0 - 3440]/dl=BYTE, [0 - 255]; out:none
                        push eax ebx
                        mov ebx, 0xb8000
                        imul eax, 2
                        inc ax
                        add ebx, eax
                        mov byte[ebx], dl
                        pop eax ebx
                        ret
                .twriteattr:   ; in:eax=ID, [0 - 3440]/dl=BYTE, [0 - 255]; out:none
                        push eax ebx
                        mov ebx, 0xb8000
                        imul eax, 2
                        add ebx, eax
                        mov byte[ebx], dl
                        pop eax ebx
                        ret
                .twritezs:     ; in:eax=POS, [0 - 3440-len(ZS)]/si=ZS, offset[0 - 32512]/dl=BYTE; out:none
                        push eax ebx
                        mov ebx, 0xb8000
                        ;imul eax, 2
                        ;inc eax
                        add ebx, eax
                    .l:
                        lodsb
                        cmp al, 0x00
                        je .ret
                        mov byte[ebx], dl
                        inc ebx
                        mov byte[ebx], al
                        inc ebx
                        jmp .l
                    .ret:
                        pop eax ebx
                        ret
```

I am analyzed code, but can't find no one mistake.

P.S.: I tested only .twritezs function, maybe another doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the things that are wrong in the code snippets:

- Everything you `push` on the stack needs to come off in reverse order (if using `pop`).
- In the video memory at 0x000B8000 the character code (ASCII) goes to the byte at the even address and the color code (attribute) goes to the byte at the odd address.

```
    push eax ebx
    lea  ebx, [0x000B8000 + eax]
    mov  ah, dl      ; Attribute
  .next:
    lodsb            ; ASCII
    cmp  al, 0
    je   .ret
    mov  [ebx], ax   ; Store ASCII at even address and Attribute at next odd address
    add  ebx, 2
    jmp  .next
  .ret:
    pop  ebx eax
    ret
```

You can get your *.twritezs* code faster if you store the ASCII (at even address) and the Attribute (at next odd address) together in one instruction.
Do notice that `(E)SI` is modified. You didn't `push` it.

---

It's not clear why you would want to multiply by 2, the value in `EAX` in the other code snippets. Isn't `EAX` already a ready-to-use offset in the video buffer, just like in the *.twritezs* code?